# Soy nuevo en JavaScript, y no entiendo la logica de las Iteraciones con For

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Yo se que esto debe ser sencillo para el 99.9% de la gente aqui, pero no logro comprender porque al hacer console.log(total) me da un resultado de 55.. Cual es la logica?

```
let total = 0

for( i = 1; i <= 10; i = i + 1){
    total += i
}
```

Comment: Creo que sin querer creaste una secuencia fibonacci

Comment: No es fibonacci, es una sumatoria del 1 al 10. `n(n+1)/2` => `10*11/2=55`

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). También te recomiendo leer las secciones [ask] y [tour] para familiarizarte con los lineamientos del sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Si pones un `console.log()` adentro del `for` vas a poser ver los valores tanto de `i` como de `total` y te ayudará a comprender el comportamiento del código.

```js
let total = 0;

for( i = 1; i <= 10; i = i + 1){
    total += i;
    console.log(i, total);
}
```

El operador `+=` que se utiliza adentro del `for`:

```
total += i;
```

Quiere decir que se aplica una suma a una variable utilizando el valor actual de la variable más un segundo valor, es decír, es equivalente a la siguiente línea:

```
total = total + i
```

Donde se utiliza el valor actual de `total` se le suma `i` para calcular el nuevo valor de `total`

Si revisas la consola del ejemplo que puse podrás ver que en cada iteración `i` aumenta en `1` y `total` es la suma del valor anterior de `total` + `i`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! Me estaba costando entender como funcionaba For! Me quedo clarisimo

Answer (score 1):

Es sencillo te explico en este caso lo que estas haciendo es sumar i a total en cada uno de sus distintos valores durante el ciclo for, por lo que en el primer recorrido

> i tiene un valor de 1

y entonces

> total = 1

Sin embargo en el segundo recorrido i tiene un valor de 2 por lo que estas básicamente diciéndole a total que ahora es

> total = 1 + 2

porque ahora

> i tiene un valor de 2

por lo que el resultado de

> total ahora es 3

en lugar de ser 2. Si deseas obtener el resultado total de las sumas de uno en uno solo debes indicarle a la variable total que aumente en 1 su numero, una opción es como te muestro en el siguiente código.

```js
let total = 0;

for( i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    total++;
}

console.log(total);
```

Quedando ahora un ciclo que aumenta en 1 cada recorrido.

Cabe aclarar que i++ o total++ simplemente lo que hace es aumentar un numero al valor actual de la variable.

Comment: Gracias @HeytalePazguato por las sugerencias

Comment: No hay de que, es más fácil entender el código cuando se puede ejecutar y ver lo que sucede, me gustaría que se pudieran insertar de la misma forma secciones de código en otros lenguajes también :(

Comment: Pues tienes toda la razón jajajaja yo la verdad no tengo tanta experiencia respondiendo pero me han ayudado tanto que, preferí responderle, y asi contribuir tambien.

Comment: Yo tengo mi cuenta desde hace algunos años, apenas el año pasado decidí empezar a responder, a principios del año tenía como 200 de reputación y la verdad es que al responder también he aprendido mucho. Éxito!

Comment: Por supuesto!! Explicado asi se entiende a la perfeccion! Era tan sencillo y me costaba encontrarle la logica xD Gracias!

Comment: Estamos para ayudar @GuillermoDiNanno